# Issues running ionic qrscanner on this page

Tags: typescript, ionic3

So im trying to implement a qr scanner on a blank page in ionic but i get an error at the first 'this' saying unexpected token then i get another error at the last curly bracket saying declaration or statement expected.

Im very new to ionic and typescript so having a bit of a hard time. This was taken directly from the ionic documentation for their native qrscanner. I also tried different code from other people but generally get the error with 'this'

Below is the entire of the code pertaining to that page. I have also added the plugin to the ngmodules in case that matters.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { QRScanner, QRScannerStatus } from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-qrcode',
  templateUrl: 'qrcode.html',
})
export class QrcodePage {

  constructor(
  public navCtrl: NavController, 
  public navParams: NavParams,
  private qrScanner: QRScanner){}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
      console.log('ionViewDidLoad QrcodePage');
  }

  this.qrScanner.prepare()
  .then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
  if (status.authorized) {
   // camera permission was granted


   // start scanning
   let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) => {
     console.log('Scanned something', text);

     this.qrScanner.hide(); // hide camera preview
     scanSub.unsubscribe(); // stop scanning
   });

   // show camera preview
   this.qrScanner.show();

   // wait for user to scan something, then the observable callback will be called

 } else if (status.denied) {
   // camera permission was permanently denied
   // you must use QRScanner.openSettings() method to guide the user to the settings page
   // then they can grant the permission from there
 } else {
   // permission was denied, but not permanently. You can ask for permission again at a later time.
 }
})
.catch((e: any) => console.log('Error is', e));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you haven't enclosed that code section in a method... see the `thereShouldBeAMethodHere()` method below. If you want to execute that code when you create a `QrcodePage` you could call that code from the constructor.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { QRScanner, QRScannerStatus } from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-qrcode',
  templateUrl: 'qrcode.html',
})
export class QrcodePage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private qrScanner: QRScanner) { }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad QrcodePage');
  }

  thereShouldBeAMethodHere() {
    this.qrScanner.prepare()
      .then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
        if (status.authorized) {
          // camera permission was granted


          // start scanning
          let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) => {
            console.log('Scanned something', text);

            this.qrScanner.hide(); // hide camera preview
            scanSub.unsubscribe(); // stop scanning
          });

          // show camera preview
          this.qrScanner.show();

          // wait for user to scan something, then the observable callback will be called

        } else if (status.denied) {
          // camera permission was permanently denied
          // you must use QRScanner.openSettings() method to guide the user to the settings page
          // then they can grant the permission from there
        } else {
          // permission was denied, but not permanently. You can ask for permission again at a later time.
        }
      })
      .catch((e: any) => console.log('Error is', e));
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow thank  you so much man. Im really new to this realm of code as im only used to learning c and c++ in school but trying to do projects on my own. So with those documentation, do you need to assign your own functions to them all ?

Comment: All of the code you place inside a class should be within a method, or on the right-hand side of a property.